# CMake linking not finding libraries

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a executable:

```
add_executable(treshhold src/main.cpp)
add_dependencies(treshhold ${PROJECT_NAME})
```

I have a directory

```
/opt/halcon/lib/x64-linux
```

which contains multiple .so files:

```
hAcqArgos3D-P1xx.so    hAcqGigEVision.so    hAcqMatrixVisionAcquire.so    hAcquEye.so            hioOPC_UA.so         libhalconcpp.so    libhalcon.so             libhdevenginecpp.so
hAcqArgos3D-P1xxxl.so  hAcqGigEVisionxl.so  hAcqMatrixVisionAcquirexl.so  hAcquEyexl.so          hioOPC_UAxl.so       libhalconcppxl.so  libhalconxl.so           libhdevenginecppxl.so
hAcqFile.so            hAcqLPS36.so         hAcqO3D3xx.so                 hAcqVideo4Linux2.so    libhalconcpp10.so    libhalconc.so      libhdevenginecpp10.so    libuastack.so
hAcqFilexl.so          hAcqLPS36xl.so       hAcqO3D3xxxl.so               hAcqVideo4Linux2xl.so  libhalconcpp10xl.so  libhalconcxl.so    libhdevenginecpp10xl.so  libusb-1.0-usan.so.0
```

linked used using and tried both:

```
include_directories(/opt/halcon/lib/x64-linux)
link_directories(/opt/halcon/lib/x64-linux)
```

But when i try a to link a certain library

```
target_link_libraries(treshhold libhalconc)
```

i get the error:

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable treshhold
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibhalconc
```

And if i try not to make the target link i get the missing reference error from the compiler.

**EDIT Full file:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(ros_halcon_bridge)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
)



add_executable(treshhold src/main.cpp)
add_dependencies(treshhold ${PROJECT_NAME})
include_directories(/opt/halcon/lib/x64-linux)
link_directories(/opt/halcon/lib/x64-linux)
target_link_libraries(treshhold libhalconc)
```

**EDIT2**
I would want to add all libraries with the following:

```
target_link_libraries(treshhold hAcqArgos3D-P1xx.so hAcqGigEVision.so hAcqMatrixVisionAcquire.so hAcquEye.so hioOPC_UA.so libhalconcpp.so libhalcon.so libhdevenginecpp.so hAcqArgos3D-P1xxxl.so hAcqGigEVisionxl.so hAcqMatrixVisionAcquirexl.so hAcquEyexl.so hioOPC_UAxl.so libhalconcppxl.so libhalconxl.so libhdevenginecppxl.so hAcqFile.so hAcqLPS36.so hAcqO3D3xx.so hAcqVideo4Linux2.so libhalconcpp10.so libhalconc.so libhdevenginecpp10.so libuastack.so hAcqFilexl.so hAcqLPS36xl.so hAcqO3D3xxxl.so hAcqVideo4Linux2xl.so libhalconcpp10xl.so libhalconcxl.so libhdevenginecpp10xl.so libusb-1.0-usan.so.0)
```

but that results in:

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable treshhold
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhAcqArgos3D-P1xx
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhAcqGigEVision
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhAcqMatrixVisionAcquire
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhAcquEye
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhioOPC_UA
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhalconcpp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhalcon
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdevenginecpp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhAcqArgos3D-P1xxxl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhAcqGigEVisionxl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhAcqMatrixVisionAcquirexl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhAcquEyexl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhioOPC_UAxl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhalconcppxl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhalconxl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdevenginecppxl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhAcqFile
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhAcqLPS36
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhAcqO3D3xx
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhAcqVideo4Linux2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhalconcpp10
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhalconc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdevenginecpp10
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -luastack
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhAcqFilexl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhAcqLPS36xl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhAcqO3D3xxxl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhAcqVideo4Linux2xl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhalconcpp10xl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhalconcxl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdevenginecpp10xl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lusb-1.0-usan
```

Comment: Are  you manually linking to `hAcqArgos3D-P1xx` anywhere else? Can you post the entire `CMakeLists.txt` file?

Comment: see the edit, i added the full file, except for the things i out commented

Comment: Have you tried just removing 'lib' from your library name?
`target_link_libraries(treshhold halconc)`

Answer (score 0):

You can see what CMake is doing with

```
make VERBOSE=1
```

Then you should be able to find out what's wrong with the generated command.

Only once you're sure about the command you really want should you bother with how to write it correctly with cmake